# $_POST loses data in included file

Tags: php

I'm making a simple CMS thingy in PHP, and I made a simple guestbook module for it.

In my `index.php` I include `template.php` (which has HTML) and calls a function which returns the content for the specific page.

```
<div id="content">
<?php content(); ?>
</div>
```

The `content` function is inside `functions.php` which is include before `template.php` inside `index.php`.

Inside `content()`:

```
print_r($_POST); // the data is displayed :)
require_once(BASE_URL_MODULES.$tempMod."/".$tempMod.".php");
```

Inside the PHP file I included (with `require_once`) all `$_POST` data is lost. `print_r($_POST)` shows a empty array.

Am I doing something wrong a.k.a. is this normal behaviour? If so, does somebody has a solution?

I'm using the ancient 4.4.9 version of PHP. Can't upgrade it because the provider doesn't want to upgrade the stuff.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend finding a new provider if your current one won't upgrade from PHP 4.4.9.

Comment: You should use [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) instead of `'/'`

Comment: Really, find a new provider.

Comment: are you sure this page is not redirected anywhere after post occurs?

Comment: Show us the actual form and all the files involved.

Comment: What is `BASE_URL_MODULES`?

Comment: Check that you are actually sending post data. try putting $_GET and adding some vars at the end of the url as a trial to see if it shows them..?

Comment: I know I really should find a new provider :P, but weird behaviour though. Alejandro, not neseccary, POST data is correct, but lost in included file. Jake N, shortcut for path to modules folder, doesnt really matter. crush, replaced it, didnt help though :(, but thanx for the tip, gonna use it in further development.

Comment: @Don Relentless, also $_GET data is lost.

Comment: include acts like its pasting the code where I post it right? Also variables created in index.php are also gone, (have $alias for example, I do global $alias; echo $alias.. nothing

Comment: Can you show us the output of `echo ini_get("variables_order");`? [variables_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure what could be preventing it from being there. Perhaps something is emptying the `$_POST` and `$_GET` data at some point as some oddly-conceived method of protecting data?

Comment: Ok, thanx for all the help. I'm updating the provider. The new one has PHP Version 5.3.27, that's better :). Will test the code on that server soon, will post the outcome. I find it very weird, it should work. But 4.4.9 is ancient as a ... so will update that first.

Comment: check phpinfo? You may have some sort of weird globals registration setting? Perhaps also upvote all comments as generally all have been helpful.

Comment: @DonRelentless register_globals = off, and I don't see upvote link :S